# dataTable becomes empty after clicking edit button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a asp.net gridview and used a jquery dataTable. The search feature works fine but the problem is after I searched and click the edit button, the table becomes empty. I used stateSave : true but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

thanks.

[image]

//jQuery code for DataTables

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: -1

    });
    $('#myTable').addClass("table table-hover");
});
```

Comment: Show your code. otherwise how are we suppose to know why?

Comment: Hi Alex, please see the code. thanks

Comment: This is styling code not insert, edit or delete code on database

Comment: Your browser supports HTML5 ?

Comment: @mck: yes, i'm using google chrome

Comment: @AlexJolig: i'm using c# for CRUD operation , not in front-end.

Comment: change stateDuration: -1 to stateDuration: 0 and check

Comment: @mck: still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

// use below code along with your ready function

```
 function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {

 $('#myTable').DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: -1
    });
    $('#myTable').addClass("table table-hover");
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi vijay: I redesigned my table, i deleted the gridview and now using repeater and modal for editing. but I'll try your code. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your searched text remains in the text box then it will automatically search's in the table again after loading. 
To avoid this you have to FALSE the saved State.

Regards,
Vijay.